# Different content types in pages

Tags: bolt-cms

I'm working on a small site that just needs to have a simple CMS to edit it's content. So I started with Bolt. At the moment I have 5 pages that has a different markup, like content structure. Is it possible to do it like this? Because at the moment it doesn't work unfortunately.

My contenttypes.yml:

```
pages:
name: Homepage
singular_name: homepage
fields:
    title:
        type: text
        class: large
        group: content
    slug:
        type: slug
        uses: title
    header-image:
        type: image
    title-one:
        type: text
    header-text:
        type: html
    title-two:
        type: text
    text-one:
        type: html
    body-image-two:
        type: image
    title-three:
        type: text
    body-image-text:
        type: html
    title-four:
        type: text
    text-two:
        type: html
    title-five:
        type: text
    text-three:
        type: html
    template:
        type: templateselect
        filter: '*.twig'
taxonomy: [ groups ]
recordsperpage: 100

name: Over ons
singular_name: over-ons
fields:
    title:
        type: text
        class: large
        group: content
    slug:
        type: slug
        uses: title
    image:
        type: image
    title-one:
        type: text
    title-two:
        type: text
    body:
        type: html
        height: 300px
    template:
        type: templateselect
        filter: '*.twig'
taxonomy: [ groups ]
recordsperpage: 100

name: Diensten
singular_name: diensten
fields:
    title:
        type: text
        class: large
        group: content
    slug:
        type: slug
        uses: title
    image:
        type: image
    title-one:
        type: text
    intro-text:
        type: html
    title-two:
        type: text
    text-two:
        type: html
    title-three:
        type: text
    text-three:
        type: html
    title-four:
        type: text
    text-four:
        type: html
    title-five:
        type: text
    text-five:
        type: html
    template:
        type: templateselect
        filter: '*.twig'
taxonomy: [ groups ]
recordsperpage: 100

name: Het proces
singular_name: het-proces
fields:
    title:
        type: text
        class: large
        group: content
    slug:
        type: slug
        uses: title
    image-one:
        type: image
    title-one:
        type: text
    intro-text:
        type: html
    title-two:
        type: text
    text-two:
        type: html
    image-two:
        type: image
    title-three:
        type: text
    text-three:
        type: html
    image-three:
        type: image
    title-four:
        type: text
    text-four:
        type: html
    image-four:
        type: image
    title-five:
        type: text
    text-five:
        type: html
    image-five:
        type: image
    title-six:
        type: text
    text-six:
        type: html
    image-six:
        type: image
    template:
        type: templateselect
        filter: '*.twig'
taxonomy: [ groups ]
recordsperpage: 100

name: Projecten
singular_name: projecten
fields:
    title:
        type: text
        class: large
        group: content
    slug:
        type: slug
        uses: title
    title-one:
        type: text
    intro-text:
        type: html
    title-two:
        type: text
    text-two:
        type: html
    image-two:
        type: image
    template:
        type: templateselect
        filter: '*.twig'
taxonomy: [ groups ]
recordsperpage: 100

name: Contact
singular_name: contact
fields:
    title:
        type: text
        class: large
        group: content
    slug:
        type: slug
        uses: title
    title-one:
        type: text
    intro-text:
        type: html
    template:
        type: templateselect
        filter: '*.twig'
taxonomy: [ groups ]
recordsperpage: 100
```

Any ideas on a solution?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest to only use one contenttype "pagina's" for that. If you need to diversify them, use the `templateselect` (like you're doing already), and perhaps add a "template field" or two.

See here: https://docs.bolt.cm/2.2/templates/building-templates#template-specific-fields